# Why does make always update this target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using *make* on my Gentoo machine (which is GNU make 3.82) with the following `Makefile`, I wonder why the target `data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat` gets updated every time I execute `make data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat`, even though none of the files `params/base/fwhm.dat`, `params/base/wavelength_grid.dat`, and `data/raw/o4green_gpp.dat` has changed, and the file `data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat` already exists:

```
FWHM = params/base/fwhm.dat
WLGRID = params/base/wavelength_grid.dat

$(WLGRID): code/create_wavelength_grid.py
    cp code/create_wavelength_grid.py params/base/wavelength_grid.dat

$(FWHM): code/create_fwhm_param.py
    cp code/create_fwhm_param.py params/base/fwhm.dat

data/raw/o4green_gpp.dat:
    echo 1 > data/raw//o4green_gpp.dat

input_spectra_o4_raw: data/raw/o4green_gpp.dat

data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat: $(WLGRID) $(FWHM) input_spectra_o4_raw 
    echo 1 > data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat

input_spectra_o4: data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat
```

Any help you guys can give a *make* newbie is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What about the `code/` files?

Comment: also those don't change.

Comment: Run `make -d`.  It will quickly (although verbosely) tell you why it decides to rebuild each target.  I strongly urge you to use automatic variables, in particular `$@` but also `$<`, in your recipes to reduce the risk of typos.

Comment: @MadScientist You should have provided this as an answer i.o. just a comment. I upvoted it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it's because there is no file named `input_spectra_o4_raw`, which is a prerequisite of your `data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat`.

The decision looks kind of like this:

```
1. params/base/wavelength_grid.dat and params/base/fwhm.dat are both up to date
2. check input_spectra_o4_raw - file does not exist, so build it first
3. there is a target for input_spectra_o4_raw, and it's prerequisite
   data/raw/o4green_gpp.dat is up to date, so run all the commands to build 
   input_spectra_o4_raw (there are none, though, so we essentially just mark that we've 
   done everything we need to for input_spectra_o4_raw and that we built it new)
4. we just built input_spectra_o4_raw, so data/spectra/o4_greenblatt_296K.dat is out of 
   date with respect to that prerequisite and needs to be rebuilt
```

You should research how to use the `.PHONY:` pseudo-target.