# GNU make always considers a non-file target as being remade (possible bug?)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Should **Make** always remake a target that has prerequisites, but does not point to a file and does not have a recipe? Or should **Make** only remake such targets if one or more of the prerequisites need to be remade?

For example, in the Makefile shown below, I added a target called `objects` that has prerequisites, but does not point to a file. 
The main target is called `program` which depends on `objects` (and potentially other prerequisites).

```
file1 file2 file3: ;       touch $@

objects: file1 file2

program: objects  file3 ;  @echo 'Making $@'
```

My expectation is that when `make program` is run and no file prerequisites need to be remade (i.e. file1, file2 and file3 all exist), that `program` should NOT be remade.

However the actual GNU **Make** behavior is that the recipe for `program` always runs (regardless of prerequisite files). This is because `objects` is always considered to be remade, which forces any dependencies (i.e. `program`) to be remade.

You can verify this by running: `make --trace -d --no-builtin-rules program` and you'll see that **Make** always outputs "*Must remake target 'objects'.*"
So `objects` is always "remade" (even though it has no recipe) and it is always considered to be newly updated.

This is most likely because `objects` does not point to a real file. But I was expecting that because it had no recipe, that it would not be remade as long as none of its prerequisites need to be remade.

**Is this the expected behavior or is it a bug?**

The [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) states:

> If a rule has no prerequisites or recipe, and the target of the rule
>   is a nonexistent file, then make imagines this target to have been
>   updated whenever its rule is run. This implies that all targets
>   depending on this one will always have their recipe run.

But that description doesn't apply to the case above, because the `objects` target **does** have prerequisites. But perhaps the behavior is the same and the **Make** manual should just be updated to clarify this.

A few additional notes:

- I used the recipe-after-semicolon format above to make it easier for
  readers to copy and paste the code. Otherwise, when copying from a
  webpage, the tabs would be converted to spaces in the usual
  tab-indented-recipe format.
- Of course I know that I could just make a variable `$(OBJECTS)` that
  would point to a list of files and use it in place of the `objects`
  target above. That's not really the point here.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764544/why-does-make-always-update-this-target) also seems to involve the same behavior, but whether or not it's the expected behavior or a bug is not discussed.
- I'm using GNU Make 4.2.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the paragraph you quoted is merely recapping a particular case of behaviour that's already specified elsewhere, in order to set the scene for how `FORCE` works.

Indeed a simpler, yet more general, statement is made in the [previous section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

> If you write a rule whose recipe will not create the target file, the recipe will be executed every time the target comes up for remaking.

And again [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html):

> A target is out of date if it does not exist or if it is older than any of the prerequisites.

So the behaviour you're observing is entirely expected.